# Paperclip validation errors not flashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm deliberately uploading a non-image file by POSTing to an iframe (fake Ajax) but I don't get the flash error.

My update action:

```
def update
    @mockup = Mockup.find_by_hash_id(params[:hash_id])
    @mockup.update_attributes(params[:mockup])
    flash[:notice] = 'Mockup updated'
      redirect_to new_or_show_mockup_path(@mockup.hash_id)
rescue Exception => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_or_show_mockup_path(@mockup.hash_id)
  end
```

My model:

```
class Mockup < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'], :message => 'Please upload an image'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add ! to update_attributes. It should be:

```
@mockup.update_attributes!(params[:mockup])
```

Otherwise it wouldn't throw an exception.